# Динамическое задание id для кнопок

Tags: java, android

Создаю кнопки динамически: сколько их будет изначально я не знаю, это зависит от длины массива.

```
for (int i = 1; i < strWord.length; i++) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            wrapContent, wrapContent);
    int btnGravity = Gravity.LEFT;
    lParams.gravity = btnGravity;
    Button btnNew = new Button(this);
    btnNew.setText(strWord[i]);
    llMain.addView(btnNew, lParams);
}
```

Далее, мне необходимо обращаться к этим кнопкам по `id`. Как мне использовать метод `.setId()`, чтобы записать `id` в массив, и потом по номеру элемента обращаться к кнопке?

Код

```
public int[] btnId;
btnId[i] = btnNew.setId(i);
```

компилятор не принимает.

Comment: ну и костыль же вы придумали!

Comment: ну извините...я только осваиваю программирование

Answer (score 2):

А почему бы не сложить кнопки в замечательный ArrayList и с id париться не надо. 
+ 
Лучше сразу кнопкам назначить листенеры что бы они сами дергали код по нажатию, тогда если задача позволяет можно вообще их в массив не собирать.

Comment: Пишу игру на подобие виселицы. После вывода кнопок на экран, с буквами присутствующими в слове, при нажатии на кнопку необходимо окрашивать её в зеленый цвет и выводить в `TextView`, при положительном результате, и в красный при отрецательном

Comment: Тогда массив и правда не нужен. Можно каждой кнопке назначить OnClickListener который одним из параметров имеет view. Его можно привести к button и делать все что угодно с ним.

Answer (score -1):

**НИКОГДА, НИКОГДА не применяйте SetId()**!!! Так вы можете случайно назначить уже существующий ID другого элемента и что тогда? 2 элемента с одинаковым ID, и тогда как понять телефону к какому элементу вы хотели обратиться, лучше доверьтесь телефону, когда создаёте ID он вам сам выдаст его, можете использовать метод **getId()** для **View** елемента

```
public int[] btnId;
btnId[i] = btnNew.getId();
```

Такой код будет более верным

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю вы используете не правильный подход. Но если очень надо то можно генерировать уникальный id при помощи View.generateViewId(), сгенерированный id не будет конфликтовать с R.id. Поэтому утверждение @BORSHEVIK не верно.

Comment: @Дмитрий Александров@ использовал **SetId()** метод установки ID своим View компонентам, по его методике может возникнуть конфликт при совпадении, что тут неверного? Чем плохи те ID, которые выдаются при создании View?

Comment: 1. При создании View из кода ей присваивается значение NO_ID.
2. При использовании View.generateViewId() он не будет конфликтовать с R.id.

Comment: Смотри исходники http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.setId%28int%29

Comment: Да, тут вы правы, но данный метод всё равно плох, лучше использовать массив Button-ов длинной в strWord.length и сравнивать с View в OnClick()

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, человек спросил как ему установить ID. :) Я ответил как. Из его условия непонятно что конкретно он хочет делать.
Если ему нужен текст из Button, то я бы установил один ClickListener на всех и в полученное при клике View доставал text.

Comment: Я из массива беру слово, разбиваю его на буквы, перемешиваю их и вывожу на динамически созданные кнопки. Далее, по нажатию на те самые кнопки, определяю в той ли они последовательности нажаты или нет и произвожу необходимые  действия над ними. Вот для этого мне и нуден `id` кнопки. Если это можно сделать как-то проще подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну ты и выдумал, а не легче болт забить и просто сравнить конечный результат со всеми словами? Я так понимаю, ты делаешь что-то на подобие филвордов. в каждом раунде одинаковых слов всё равно не будет.